# How can I only see version-specific Django documentation in Google search results?

Tags: django, google-search

This is a bit of an oddball request but I'm sure any Django dev worth their salt has spent a bit of time reading a piece (or a fairly good sized chunk!) of Django documentation only to realize it's horribly out of data and no longer relevant.

Is there a Google query parameter that might help or a cookie on the Django documentation page that could be set by the user?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways you can check/change the documentation version :

1. In the url
2. Bottom right corner on docs